# Why is PHP sql code not inserting into database, trying to make register

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
  require_once("db_credentials.php");
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "isdc3333", "collab_schema");
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["first"]);
  $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["last"]);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
  $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["uid"]);
  $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["pwd"]);

  if (empty($first) or empty($last) or empty($email) or empty($uid) or 
  empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: signup.php?signup=empty");
    exit();
  } else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) or !preg_match("/^[a-zA- 
    Z]*$/", $last)) {
      header("Location: signup.php?signup=invalid");
      exit();
    } else {
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: signup.php");
        exit();
      } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($queryResults > 0) {
          header("Location: signup.php?signup=usertaken");
          exit();
        } else {
          $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          $sql = "INSERT INTO collab_schema.users (first, last, email, uid, 
          pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', 
          '$hashedPwd');";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          header("Location: signup.php?signup=success");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
} else {
header("Location: signup.php");
exit();
echo "Redirecting...";
}
?>
```

The last sql query won't work, can you list the errors?
Doesn't look like the code is working, but everyone says it fine.
I'm just putting more text because stack overflow says to put more details even when I don't want too :^)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I didn't even concatenate

Comment: I specifically say "interpolation or concatenation" and you absolutely are concatenating. This code is one slip away from disaster. It may already have SQL injection bugs, but you won't know unless you back-track every single interpolated variable to its source. With prepared statements that use placeholder values those sorts of slips are impossible to do by accident.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with procdeural php? Because I don't know object oriented

Comment: I'm copying from a video and now I'm asking how did he do it:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb8aad4MRx8

Comment: Go to 1:06:32 :)

Comment: YouTube offers the ability to add timestamps to links.

Comment: not the point but ok

Comment: That tutorial might explain how a login system works, but please, **DO NOT** use this on a production site. This is not production quality code and anything less than that will expose you, your users, your business, and possibly your career to extreme risk. Use a login system produced by professionals, that's been reviewed for security flaws, and is supported by a community of developers.

Comment: I just want to do it at home, I'm not using that for work

Comment: That tutorial is atrociously bad and yet another reason why one of the biggest detriments to the improvement of PHP as a language and a community is YouTube. Can people please, please, please stop making these "tutorials"?

Comment: Procedural and object-oriented are, in the case of `mysqli`, just two sides of exactly the same coin. Object oriented programming isn't all that complicated, it just takes a different form. Instead of `f($x, $y)` you do `$x->f($y)` where the function *acts on* something instead of that something being supplied as an argument. The main advantage of object-oriented programming is *namespaces* where instead of having thousands of top-level functions they're all organized into different classes.

Comment: My advice: Stay *away* from "tutorials", especially the low-quality garbage floating around on YouTube. Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with confused concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: Make sure you get in the right if else conditions. Do you get redirected to Location: signup.php?signup=success when you submit the form. If not, where do you get?